# Adding text above barplot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

suppose I have the following barplot (the barplot can be created with the code)

```
set.seed(999)

similarity_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
similarity_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)

attraction_prop_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
attraction_prop_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)

compromise_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
compromise_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)

library(tidyverse)

# add all matrices in a list. I use lst here since the ouptut is 
# a named list 
lst(similarity_context_set1,
    similarity_context_set2,
    attraction_prop_context_set2,
    attraction_prop_context_set1,
    compromise_context_set1,
    compromise_context_set2) %>% 
  # transform to tibble and add column names
  map(as_tibble) %>% 
  map(set_names, c("X", "Y","Third")) %>% 
  # bind the list to one dataframe, add list names to column by 
  # setting .id
  bind_rows(.id = "name") %>% 
  # transform data from wide to long as it is recommended ggplot 
  #input format here
pivot_longer(-1,names_to = "x", values_to = "y") %>% 
  # make to columns for facetting
  separate(name, into = c("name1", "name2"), sep = "_", extra = "merge") %>% 
  mutate(name2 = str_extract(name2, "[0-9]")) %>% 
  # finally the plot
  ggplot(aes(x, y, group=x, fill = x)) + theme_hc(base_size = 13)+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean",alpha=0.8 )+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Y" = "gray1","X" = "gray1","Third" = "gray1"), guide="none" )+
  facet_grid(name2~name1)+ 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width=0.2)+
  ggtitle("Perceptual Domain")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(x = "Response", y = "Mean Choice Proportion")
```

How can I add an individual text above each bar? I don't want to write the average values above the bars, but a text like on the picture (Target, Competitor and Third)  B[image]ild?

Do you know how I can additionally add different lines for each plot with labels? like this:
[image]

Comment: How do you decide which labels you want above which bars? The labels are not present in your data structure, nor is it obvious how you are arriving at your choice for which label goes where in each panel.

Comment: Yes, that is the point. I want to insert the text individually without it being present in the data structure. if this is not possible how can i include the labels in the data structure so that i can then display it in the barplot

Comment: you can add multiple annotations, or simply create a little data frame for your labels, as I show in my answer below.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how I can additionally add different lines for each plot with labels? like this in the picture above

Comment: For a new question, please kindly ask a follow up question - please also don't forget to link to this thread here and to include the code used for this example, in this case, Allans code. Thanks

Comment: for reference, this has already been asked now by the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71159521/how-can-i-add-lines-with-labels-to-a-barplot-using-ggplot2

Answer (score 3):

If you have this many labels to insert and want complete control over the order, then the easiest way is probably to create a little label data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(name1 = rep(rep(c("attraction", "compromise", "similarity"), each = 3), 2),
                 name2 = rep(c("1", "2"), each = 9),
                 x     = rep(c("Third", "X", "Y"), 6),
                 y     = rep(12, 18),
                 label = c("Now", "you", "can", "use", "any", "label", "you", "want",
                           "by", "inserting", "it", "as", "a", "string", "into", "this", 
                           "character", "vector"))
```

Then if you add this line anywhere in your plot code:

```r
geom_text(data = df, aes(label = label))
```

You will get:

[image]

Comment: Allan, may I ask if you have used an automated way of creating that character vector for the labels or have you manually added all those quotation marks???

Comment: also you get my upvote just for coming up with this meaningful sentence of exactly 18 words.

Comment: I'm afraid to say this was manual @tjebo, though I could have used dput and strsplit I suppose!