# How can I add lines with labels to a barplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

You can copy the following code for the example which creates a barplot using `ggplot2`:

```
set.seed(999)


similarity_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
similarity_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)

attraction_prop_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
attraction_prop_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)

compromise_context_set1 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)
compromise_context_set2 = matrix(rnorm(10*3,10,1),ncol=3)

library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

# add all matrices in a list. I use lst here since the ouptut is 
# a named list 


df <- data.frame(name1 = rep(rep(c("attraction", "compromise", "similarity"), each = 3), 2),
                 name2 = rep(c("1", "2"), each = 9),
                 x     = rep(c("Third", "X", "Y"), 6),
                 y     = rep(12, 18),
                 label = c("Now", "you", "can", "use", "any", "label", "you", "want",
                           "by", "inserting", "it", "as", "a", "string", "into", "this", 
                           "character", "vector"))

lst(similarity_context_set1,
    similarity_context_set2,
    attraction_prop_context_set2,
    attraction_prop_context_set1,
    compromise_context_set1,
    compromise_context_set2) %>% 
  # transform to tibble and add column names
  map(as_tibble) %>% 
  map(set_names, c("X", "Y","Third")) %>% 
  # bind the list to one dataframe, add list names to column by 
  # setting .id
  bind_rows(.id = "name") %>% 
  # transform data from wide to long as it is recommended ggplot 
  #input format here
  pivot_longer(-1,names_to = "x", values_to = "y") %>% 
  # make to columns for facetting
  separate(name, into = c("name1", "name2"), sep = "_", extra = "merge") %>% 
  mutate(name2 = str_extract(name2, "[0-9]")) %>% 
  # finally the plot
  ggplot(aes(x, y, group=x, fill = x)) + theme_hc(base_size = 13)+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean",alpha=0.8 )+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Y" = "gray1","X" = "gray1","Third" = "gray1"), guide="none" )+
  facet_grid(name2~name1)+ 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width=0.2)+
  ggtitle("Perceptual Domain")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(x = "Response", y = "Mean Choice Proportion")+
  geom_text(data = df, aes(label = label))
```

My question is how can I add different lines with labels? On the picture below you can see an example of what I mean:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea how I can do something like that?

Comment: Take a look at `geom_hline()`

Comment: can you do it??

Comment: here for reference the question to which this one here is a follow up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71158103/adding-text-above-barplot-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 1):

This is much the same as your last question, and the answer much the same as the last answer. Please take time to read and understand what is happening in the code.

Create this data frame:

```r
df2 <- data.frame(name1 = rep(c("attraction", "compromise", "similarity"), 2),
                  name2 = rep(c("1", "2"), each = 3),
                  yintercept  = runif(6, 5, 10),
                  label = c("Now", "use", "whatever", 
                            "label", "you", "like"))
```

And add this line:

```r
geomtextpath::geom_texthline(data = df2, aes(yintercept = yintercept, label = label),
    color = "red", size = 6, hjust = 0.8, vjust = -0.2, fontface = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I personally feel it is a good follow up question and an even better answer. I was just missing the reference to the first question. (i've linked to this now in the comments)

Comment: @tjebo it felt easier coming up with a six-word sentence than an 18-word sentence!

Comment: haha! well done in both cases. I really need to have a proper look at your package, all those different geoms are simply amazing!

Comment: @AllanCameron II tried to download your package. I get: Error: package or namespace load failed for 'geomtextpath' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 Namespace 'systemfonts' 0.3.2 is already loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is requested
Additionally: warning message:
Package 'geomtextpath' was created under R version 4.0.5

Comment: @Rologist sounds like you need to update the `systemfonts` package?